# What does a AA battery marked with R6P mean?

Tags: batteries

So I found on Quora.com in the name LR6 battery that the L stands for alkaline, the R stands for round, and the 6 means it's a AA size battery. However I have another AA battery with the name R6P. In this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32305/recharging-zinc-carbon-batteries-if-an-aa-r6p-is-a-zinc-carbon-anyway) on this site it's said that R6P can both be zinc-carbon or manganese-zinc. Is there a meaning of the R and the P in this? Is there a place that shows what these letters mean? On this R6P battery it says "not to be substituted for alkaline (LR) batteries. Does this mean it has limited uses? For example can I use it for a wireless mouse or keyboard?

Edit: Also, both LR6 and the R6P are marked 1.5 volts. I've just opened up the R6P battery and it looks like this:

[image]

Also, I've read a bit about [zinc-carbon batteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc%E2%80%93carbon_battery), the article at Wikipedia says that the chemical reactions is from zinc and manganese dioxide. So in the question I linked does zinc-carbon and manganese-zinc mean the same thing?

I've just looked up manganese oxide and it look exactly like what I saw as the filling around the rod. It looked like this:
[Manganese dioxide](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manganese_dioxide#/media/File:Manganese-dioxide-sample.jpg)

So I guess the centre rod is carbon and the filling around it is manganese dioxide?

Answer (score 2):

The R6P can have a slightly higher voltage than the LR6.  The LR6 can supply more current than the R6P.  Either would most likely work fine in a wireless mouse or keyboard as the current consumption isn't too high.

The [Wikipedia article on battery nomenclature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_nomenclature) explains the letter codes.

In this case the L prefix designates a specific chemistry, while the P suffix designates performance levels of the plain R6 type.

Comment: Can you provide any information about how these designations are defined? Can you point to a reference somewhere? I'm not doubting what you say, I'm just really curious.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson These things are hard to find.  R6 is the official IEC designation.  The L and P indicate chemistry, but I cannot find a standard.  This is the best I could find in a quick search: [link](https://www.ennoproducts.com/info/lr6-battery-compared-with-r6p-battery-25647247.html)

Comment: The question was what R6P means. The wiki article is vast, so could you just apply it and give a straight answer? My reading is that R6P is a "zinc-carbon" battery (no prefix), round type, size "6", performance grade "P". And explanation of performance suffixes is missing from Wikipedia, and the last table doesn't contain "P" suffix. So the question has still no formal answer.

Comment: I just went looking for what "heavy-duty" means in the context of an R03P (AAA battery), and about the P modifier, the best I could find is a reference to "P-system" in a some table of contents for IEC 60086. Not sure this is it, but I do wonder what the "P" modifier does.